# Query returns rows outside of `between` range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I am querying a SQL Server database to get results from a table between two number values.  Here is that statement:

```
select *
FROM [DATA].[dbo].[TableName] with (nolock)
where number between '1400' and '1500'
order by CAST(number as float);
```

For the most part, the results are within the range as expected.  However, I do see some anomalies where a number that has the first four digits within the range is returned as a result.  For example:

```
14550
```

In the result above, the first four digits are `1455` which would be within the range of `1400` to `1500`.  My guess is that this has to do with the `CAST(number as float)` part of the statement.  Any suggestions on how I can update this statement to only return numbers between the stated values?

Here is the `number` info I get when running `sp_help`:

```
| Column_name   | Type          | Computed  | Length  | Prec | Scale    | Nullable  | TrimTrailingBlanks  | FixedLenNullInSource  | Collation                                       |
=============================================================================================================================================================
| NUMBER        | varchar       | no        | 4000      |      |        | yes       | no                | yes               | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  |
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `nolock` willy nilly, you really shouldn't store numbers as strings, and you really shouldn't cast numbers to float - why are you doing that? All that said, we need a [mre] in order to assist... i.e. sample data, actual results and expected results.

Comment: looks like column `number` is string. For string `14550`, it is indeed between `1400` and `1500`

Comment: Exactly, strings aren't numbers and are compared differently. Use the correct datatype (not float) and save yourself a load of pain.

Comment: Is there a way to work with the value as a `VARCHAR` to get the desired results?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You've already used `cast` so are clearly familiar with the concept, just cast number (to an int not a float). But that will screw your performance because it will have to convert every value in the database i.e. ignore any indexes. Wow 4000 bytes to store some ints that would fit into 4 bytes?

Comment: @DaleK Due to the restrictions that I have on interacting with the database.  I am unable to alter the column type.

Comment: @DaleK ha... okay.  So the answer is no way to do it.

Comment: @codacopia - Assuming your number column is strictly  numeric values and doesn't have any other characters, you can CAST number as an INT

Comment: @codacopia I explained how in my earlier comment? Just cast... and take the performance hit... and don't use float... and don't use nolock.

Comment: @ItalianStallion4215 I just tried `INT` but it still gave the results described in the question.

Comment: @codacopia you must have done it wrong... show your actual code. Compare `select * from (values ('14550')) as X (num) where num between '1400' and '1500'; select * from (values ('14550')) as X (num) where cast(num as int) between 1400 and 1500;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison is being done as a string, because a column named `number` is stored as a string and the comparison values are strings.  You could easily fix this just by changing the comparison values to numbers:

```
select *
FROM [DATA].[dbo].[TableName] 
where number between 1400 and 1500
order by CAST(number as float);
```

But this is a hacky solution -- and it will return an error if any of the `number` values are not numbers.  The real solution is to fix the data model, so it is not storing numbers as strings:

```
alter table tablename alter number int;
```

This uses `int` because all the referenced values in the question are ints.

If you cannot do this because the column is erroneously called `number` and contains non-numbers, then use a safe conversion function:

```
select *
FROM [DATA].[dbo].[TableName] 
where try_cast(number as float) between 1400 and 1500
order by try_cast(number as float);
```

Note:  I'm also not sure if this is the logic you really want, because it includes 1500.  You might really want:

```
select *
FROM [DATA].[dbo].[TableName] 
where try_cast(number as float) >= 1400 and
      try_cast(number as float) < 1500
order by try_cast(number as float);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the number as an int...

```
select *
FROM [DATA].[dbo].[TableName]
where CAST(number as int) between 1400 and 1500
order by CAST(number as int);
```

Comment: AND use numerical values in the between statement - which you have done - but that in fact is the most important bit.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for also pointing that out. It's like second nature to me, so forgot to mention that lol